# Binary relation finding the transitive closure

Tags: relations, binary

Let $A=\{a,b,c\}$ and the relation given by the following matrix: $\mathcal M_r=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$

The task is to find the smallest transitive relation $E$ such that $r\subseteq E$. Which is equivalent of saying find the transitive closure of $r$.

so what I know is that: $t(r)=\cup_{n\geq0}r^n, r^n=r\circ r\circ r\circ...\circ r, n$ times.

so $\mathcal M_{t(r)}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal (M_r)^n$ and this gives me $$\mathcal M_{t(r)}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&0\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Is there something wrong in my approach?

Comment: It's not clear how do you calculate $\mathcal M_r^n$ and their sum?

Comment: @Berci Using logic operators, $+$ is denoted as OR and $.$ is denoted as AND. And $n$ is the cardinal of set $A$

Comment: The result is correct. For this specific small example there's a shorter way to solve, though.

Comment: @Berci Which way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct

If our graph is small like this, we can simply draw it (loops at $a$ and $b$ and arrows $a\to c,\ b\to c,\ c\to a$), and then use that we have an arrow $x\to y$ in the transitive closure iff there is a *path* $x\leadsto y$ in the original graph.